# DIV with 100% height is too tall even without content

Tags: css, height, footer, sticky-footer

I'm trying to implement a [sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) which is working except that the main wrapping div's 100% height is extending way too tall (#body-wrap) and it's causing a huge gap between the content and the footer.  So instead of the footer sitting at the bottom of the screen like it's supposed to, I have to scroll down the page past the huge gap to view it.

I have something like this as my HTML:

```
<div id="body-wrap">

    <div id="content">

             [about 100px of content here]

    </div><!-- end #content -->

<div class="push"></div>

</div><!-- end #body-wrap -->

<div id="footer-wrap">

    <div id="footer-content">

              [about 300px of content here]

    </div> <!-- end #footer-content -->

</div> <!-- end #footer-wrap -->
```

And my CSS:

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
}

#body-wrap {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -300px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's   height */
 }

.footer-main-wrap, .push {
height: 300px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}
```

Anyone have any idea why the a 100% height would extend further than the content?

Comment: Did you also forget to add the quotation mark, `"` in your original source? When I prepared my answer, the missing occurence of a closing quotation mark resulted in a different lay-out (FF 3.6.22).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you specify height as a percentage (e.g., `height: 100%`), that's in relation to the *parent* container, not the *contents* of the element.  If you're not needing to support IE6, you'll probably find this a lot easier to implement using `position: fixed` for the footer.

---

Edit: I just noticed another thing - in your markup you have an element with ID `footer-wrap`, but in your CSS, you're using the selector `.footer-main-wrap`.  Try changing `.footer-main-wrap` in your CSS to `#footer-wrap`.

Comment: You were right about it taking the height of a parent div.  That seemed to fix the issue of the 100% height going way too long.  But now I have an issue with a large gap below my footer.  hmmm...

Comment: How large is the gap?  If it's in the order of 10-15px or so, it could be the default margin on the body element.  @Rob's answer there would be helpful, i.e., put `body { margin: 0; }` in your style sheet.

Comment: The bottm gap is about 180px.  Adding body { margin: 0; } doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Just noticed some mismatching between your CSS and markup - check out the updated answer.

Comment: That's just a typo here. It's the correct selector on my site.

Answer (score 0):

Adding
`height 100%` to your html
and
`height` `auto` to your `body` will make it adjust correctly when the page isn't long enough